# How to populate the data scraped from API in node js into EJS template

Tags: node.js, json, web-scraping

My index.js file on root directory

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const path = require("path");
const axios = require("axios").default;
const cors = require("cors");
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "/views"));

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
  })
);

fetchData = async () => {
  const data = await axios.get(
    "https://nepse-data-api.herokuapp.com/data/todaysprice"
  );
  console.log(data);
  return data;
};

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  const nepseData = fetchData();
  res.render("home.ejs", { nepseData });
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("listening to port 3000");
});
```

My home.ejs file on views directory

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= nepseData %>
  </body>
</html>
```

The browser is displaying this when I run the server

[image]

The API is sending this type of data
[image]

I want to show the name and prices on my ejs file. What should I do now??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add `await` there:

```
app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  const nepseData = await fetchData();
  res.render("home.ejs", { nepseData });
});
```

And then you can iterate over the data:

```
<% nepseData.forEach(function(row){ %>

   <%= row.companyName %> <%= row.minPrice %>

<% }); %>
```

Comment: did not worked. Await keyword works only on async functions.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Edited it.

Comment: Bro thank you sooo much. Solved it.